# Error in BLTK Documentation Usage: 'dict_vectorizer' Module Issue in Google Colab – Seeking a Solution

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, preprocessor

[Error Massage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqQJq.png)
I was following [BLTK Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/bltk/) for preprocessing bangali texts and practicing in google colab.

When I ran this code , I have got an error.
It seems "dict_vectorizer" is probably moved to a different module. I am not sure about the issue.

I tried to find out the solution from google, but I was unable to find working solution.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: This exact [issue](https://github.com/saimoncse19/bltk/issues/2) was already mentioned in their GitHub which apparently didn't get resolved.